# What is the effect of "this" keyword when used alone?

Tags: solidity

I came across the following code, which uses "this" as a standalone statement. What is its effect?

```
fallback() external {
  (bool result,) = address(delegate).delegatecall(msg.data);
  if (result) {
    this;
  }
}
```